# How to send HttpRequest, and it returns Json data and display it

Tags: javascript, json

I got very confused on getting Json data. Please correct me if anything does wrong. Below is 
my code:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("getListings").innerHTML=data;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://getJsonData",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Datetime","Fri, 15 Feb 2013 00:00:00 GMT");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization","XXXXXXX");
xmlhttp.send();
```

I could not get anything displayed on "getListings" div.

Comment: How come you don't use jQuery? The jQuery.ajax() is perfect for this

Comment: Hi, how do I use jQuery.ajax() to send HTTPRequest?

Comment: mclaassen made a fine answer

Comment: You can try the jQuery $.ajax() method offered by jQuery. You can follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424376/problem-with-jquery-ajax-parameters

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://getJsonData",
    dataType: "json",
    success: processData,
    error: function(){ alert("failed"); }
});

function processData(data)
{
    //do something with data
}
```

Also, not sure what you're expecting just setting the innerHtml to the json object itself, you probably want to get some sort of propery value form the json by using `data.someProperty`

Comment: @user1667419 You might want to add console.log(data); inside the processData function if its your first time trying it

Comment: Thx for your response. For what I get, it seems like I also need to append "Accept-Datetime" and "Authorization" in the request header. Where do I add it if using $.ajax?

Comment: If you need authorization you can do it with the beforeSend setting: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - you need to be sure you need it though (I'm just guessing but you probably don't)

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues:

`xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

You should use:

`xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')`

But, I would go with `httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');` as this tells the server you want to accept JSON, yours states you are sending JSON.

Now, when you parse the JSON, you may want to look at this: [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript) as not all browsers can parse JSON.

Now, when you parse, you will want to look at not just putting it into the innerhtml, but format it and then put the formatted html code into the innerhtml if you desire.

A simple way to see if you are parsing it properly is to have an alert just show one property in the json.